# Token not being sent in headers on API request

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, express, deployment

[This is the screenshow of what is happening when I am logged in and going to cart it is showing index-g_1cnTna.js:179 GET https://ecommerce-kdk6.onrender.com/api/v1/cart/get-cart 401 (Unauthorized)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bj72a.png)I am facing an issue where the authentication token is not being sent in the headers of my API requests, specifically when making a request to the /api/v1/cart/get-cart endpoint. The application is built using Express for the backend and a frontend framework for the client side.
have implemented token generation and set it as a cookie upon successful user login.
The cookie is being set with the correct attributes (httpOnly: true, sameSite: 'None', secure: true).
However, when making a request to /api/v1/cart/get-cart, the token is not present in the headers, resulting in a 401 Unauthorized response.

UserRouter.js

```
    userRouter.post("/login", async (req, res) => {
  const { email, password } = req.body;

  try {
    const user = await User.findOne({ email }).select('+password');
    console.log(user);
    if (!user) {
      return res.status(401).send("User with this email could not be found");
    }

    const isPassword = await bcrypt.compare(password,user.password) 

    if (isPassword) {
      // Generate a JWT
      const token = jwt.sign({ userId: user._id }, "DHRUV", {
        expiresIn: "1h",
      });

      // Set the token in a cookie (httpOnly for security)
      res.cookie("token", token, { httpOnly: true, sameSite: 'None', secure: true });



      // Return user information and token in the response
      res.json({ user, token });
    } else {
      return res.status(401).send("Incorrect password");
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    res.status(500).send("Server Error");
  }
});
```

Auth.js

```
const isAuthenticated = async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
      const token = req.cookies.token;
  
      if (!token) {
        return res.status(401).send("Unauthorized: No token found");
      }
  
      const decoded = jwt.decode(token);
  
      if (!decoded || !decoded.userId) {
        return res.status(401).send("Unauthorized: Invalid token");
      }
  
      const userId = decoded.userId;
      req.user = await User.findById(userId);
  
      if (!req.user) {
        return res.status(401).send("Unauthorized: User not found");
      }
  
      next();
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
      res.status(500).send("Server Error");
    }
  };
```

app.js

```
import express from "express";
import { productrouter } from "./routes/productroute.js";
import multer from "multer";
import { userRouter } from "./routes/user.js";
import cookieParser from "cookie-parser";
import { orderRouter } from "./routes/order.js";
import cors from 'cors';
import { cartRouter } from "./routes/cart.js";
import {v2 as cloudinary} from 'cloudinary';

export const app = express();
// console.log(process.env.CLOUD_NAME)

app.use(express.json())
app.use(cookieParser())
app.use(cors({ origin: 'https://dash-deals.onrender.com', credentials: true }))

app.use('/api/v1/products', productrouter)
app.use('/api/v1/cart', cartRouter)
app.use('/api/v1/users', userRouter);
app.use('/api/v1/orders', orderRouter);
```

client side code

```
 const fetchCart = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch('https://ecommerce-kdk6.onrender.com/api/v1/cart/get-cart', {
        method: 'GET',
        credentials: 'include',
      });

      const data = await response.json();
      return data.cart;
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('first login or register.', error);
    }
  };
```

I have verified that the token is present in the browser's cookies. Also it is working fine in dev Environment

Comment: Can you share the client side request code? Did you verify that the cookie is being attached to other requests? What makes you confident that the cookie is correctly set for your hostname?

Comment: i have shared client side code now.

Comment: Does your cookie location include the `ecommerce-kdk6.onrender.com/api` endpoint? Otherwise the browser will not include that cookie in the request.

Comment: No i think as i am just doing this  res.cookie("token", token, { httpOnly: true, sameSite: 'None', secure: true });

Comment: Which of the "Unauthorized" responses are you getting? "No token found" "Invalid token" or "User not found"?

Comment: Unauthorized: No token found

Comment: i have attached screenshot also

Comment: why does it mention a cross-site context?

Comment: this issues arrive when i used and integrate stripe for payments in my e-commerce project